# Hibernate persists only first nested entity

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, transient

My problem is that Hibernate does not persist nested entities given in entity.

Consider following entities:

**PollEntity**

```
@Table(name = "\"poll\"")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Builder
public class PollEntity {

    @Transient
    public OptionEntity addOption(OptionEntity pollOptionEntity) {
        if(options == null)
            options = new HashSet<>();
        options.add(pollOptionEntity);
        pollOptionEntity.setPoll(this);
        return pollOptionEntity;
    }

    @Transient
    public OptionEntity dropOption(OptionEntity pollOptionEntity) {
        options.remove(pollOptionEntity);
        pollOptionEntity.setPoll(null);
        return pollOptionEntity;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @Column(name = "author")
    @UUIDv4
    private UUID author;
    @Column(name = "poll_question")
    @Size(max = 1000)
    private String pollQuestion;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "poll", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @Builder.Default
    @Valid
    private Set<OptionEntity> options;
}
```

**OptionEntity**

```
@Table(name = "\"option\"")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Builder
public class OptionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "poll_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private PollEntity poll;
    @Column(name = "option")
    @Size(max = 1000)
    @NotNull
    private String option;
}
```

And here's service method:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void createPoll(@Valid PollEntity pollEntity) throws ValidationException {
    validationService.validateOrThrow(pollEntity);
    if (pollRepository.findById(pollEntity.getId()).isPresent())
        throw new ValidationException("Invalid id", Map.of("id", "Poll with id (" + pollEntity.getId() + ") already exists"));
    pollEntity = validationService.validateAndSave(pollRepository, pollEntity);
```

And corresponding test:

```
@Test
public void createPollTest() throws ValidationException {
    var uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    var pollOption1 = OptionEntity.builder()
        .option("Test option 1")
        .build();
    var pollOption2 = OptionEntity.builder()
        .option("Test option 2")
        .build();
    var pollOption3 = OptionEntity.builder()
        .option("Test option 3")
        .build();
    var poll = PollEntity.builder()
        .id(uuid)
        .pollQuestion("Test question")
        .author(UUID.randomUUID())
        .build();
    poll.addOption(pollOption1);
    poll.addOption(pollOption2);
    poll.addOption(pollOption3);
    pollService.createPoll(poll);
}
```

Which gives following output in database

poll

`2e565f50-7cd4-4fc9-98cd-49e0f0964487 feae5781-ff07-4a21-9292-c11c4f1a047d    Test question`

option

`c786fe5d-632d-4e94-95ef-26ab2af633e7 fc712242-8e87-41d8-93f2-ff0931020a4a    Test option 1`

and rest options ended up unpersisted.

I've also used to create options in separate method

```
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public Set<OptionEntity> createOptions(@Valid Set<OptionEntity> pollOptionsEntities) throws ValidationException {
    for (var pollOption : pollOptionsEntities) {
        validationService.validateAndSave(pollOptionsRepository, pollOption);
    }
    return pollOptionsEntities;
}
```

and option entities were getting produced but had to switch to persisting from built-in entity methods due to errors with persisting poll entity.

Database schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "poll"
(
    "id"            UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    "author"        UUID          NOT NULL,
    "poll_question" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE "option"
(
    "id"         UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    "poll_id"    UUID          NOT NULL REFERENCES "poll" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
    "option"     VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
)
```

What are the possible approaches to try?

**UPD 1**

Having considered various looking-alike questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132684/nesting-multiple-entities-hibernate-giving-issues),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028053/cant-persist-a-hashset-in-hibernate),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248001/save-value-type-collection-in-hibernate),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638723/how-should-equals-and-hashcode-be-implemented-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125210/hibernate-persistentset-remove-operation-not-working))

I've came up with this addition to entity which suppose make entities persistence regardless of actual value and still having only one option in output. What was done wrong?

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if ( object == this ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( object == null || object.getClass() != getClass() ) {
        return false;
    }
    final OptionEntity other = OptionEntity.class.cast( object );
    if ( getId() == null && other.getId() == null ) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder( 17, 37 );
    if ( id == null ) {
        while (getOptions().iterator().hasNext())
            hcb.append( getOptions().iterator().next() );
    }
    else {
        hcb.append( id );
    }
    hcb.append( options );
    return hcb.toHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer were quite trivial all the way long.

In order to overcome this the only thing that should be done is to change container: `Set<OptionEntity>` to `List<OptionEntity>`.

Hope this will not produce some hard-to-tackle bugs but if it can - please add comment.

Because in my case uniqueness was not strict requirement, ended up with this:

PollEntity:

```
@Table(name = "\"poll\"")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
public class PollEntity {

    @Transient
    public OptionEntity addOption(OptionEntity pollOptionEntity) {
        options.add(pollOptionEntity);
        pollOptionEntity.setPoll(this);
        return pollOptionEntity;
    }

    @Transient
    public OptionEntity dropOption(OptionEntity pollOptionEntity) {
        options.remove(pollOptionEntity);
        pollOptionEntity.setPoll(null);
        return pollOptionEntity;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private Status status;
    @Column(name = "author")
    @UUIDv4
    private UUID author;
    @Column(name = "poll_question")
    @Size(max = 1000)
    private String pollQuestion;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "poll", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @Builder.Default
    @Valid
    private List<OptionEntity> options = new ArrayList<>();
}
```